# How to fetch the merge information from a pull request in GIT

Tags: git

I am trying to get the commit ID, author name, merged date, Commit date, Modified filenames, commit message, and the source branch for all the merge requests after a specific date to a particular branch.

```
git log --merges --date=short --since "2021-07-30" --first-parent <ReleaseBranchname> --pretty="%h|%an|%ad|%s|"
```

Output --> 7b8756b||2021-07-31|Merged in  (pull request #1)|

Expected Output

```
7b8756b|<Author name>|<Merged Date>|<Commit date>|<filename1>|<SourceBranchName1>|<Commit message1>| 
7b8756b|<Author name>|<Merged Date>|<Commit date>|<filename2>|<SourceBranchName1>|<Commit message1>|
123456Z|<Author name>|<Merged Date>|<Commit date>|<filename3>|<SourceBranchName2>|<Commit message2>|
```

can someone please suggest?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Git itself does not know about pull requests / merge requests, and for the most part doesn't care about branch names (they're temporary pointers to some commit, not permanent metadata), so some of the information you are asking for simply doesn't exist in git's database.

Comment: Thanks for your response @IMSoP. I have modified the code and getting the below output now   <code> git log --merges --date=short --since "2021-07-30" --name-only --first-parent release_merge_test --pretty="%h|%an|%ad|%s|" </code>. Output --> 7b8756b|<Merged By>|<Merged Date>|<merge Title>|                                                                                                        
 <filename1><filename2> . Can I get the output such as Filenames can also come in the same record. Also, how can I retrieve the author name who has commited the change instead of the person merging. TIA!